# Review audit: Answer marked as spam, unclear why

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Today I hit a review audit failure. I tagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7565779) as "Looks OK", yet the audit told me it should've been "Recommend Deletion". I am not sure why. Albeit a short one, the answer seems legit and I also checked the link to YouTube to verify if it was on-topic and it is.

The answer does have this note: "This answer was marked as spam or offensive", which is probably the issue. But why is this answer considered as spam/offensive? Because it contains a link to a YouTube video? I'm not sure if that should always count as spam, the linked video is actually on-topic and might help the OP a lot.

Can anybody clarify this to me so I can actually learn from this? Because currently, I have no clue what I've done wrong and would do the same again tomorrow.

Comment: You failed 'cause it had been deleted as spam; so the question you actually want to ask is why this answer was deemed to be spam. The answer to that question is slightly less obvious...

Comment: Suggesting to use Fiddler counts as spam now? I didn't get the memo.

Comment: @Louis Yes, but it is an on-topic video about the issue the OP is asking about. Is that still not allowed?

Comment: @Ben Good point, updated the question.

Comment: ["at 20 LQ reviews a day limit, one has plenty time to do more thorough check of reviewed posts..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287917/839601)

Comment: Although I'm very ignorant of the subject matter, the answer appears to me at a glance to be poor quality regardless of whether it's spam or not. Poorly formatted code snippet and a link with little explanation.

Answer (score 8):

That was spam for a YouTube channel by the answerer. I don't believe it was the only such post they made like that, all linking back to their channel.

This is getting to be a more popular kind of spam on Stack Overflow recently. Users will try to spam older, established questions with links to their YouTube videos (which always have ads on them) in an attempt to earn revenue from SO traffic. As a result, you should be suspicious of old, highly voted questions getting answers by new users that only seem to exist in order to link to a YouTube video.

This particular post was flagged as spam, deleted, and the user behind it destroyed. As a result, it became an audit case. I think it's a decent one, given the volume of this kind of spam we're seeing currently.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, although I still think it's debatable whenever a YT link becomes spam. I agree with the fact that a user should not always link to their own channel to get more traffic, but if the video is relevant and on-topic, it's not really spam IMHO. Also in the review process, it's hard to tell if the user has done this before (unless you open their profile and view all their answers (and you can only view deleted ones with 10k+ rep)), so I'm still in doubt about the audit value of this. :-\