# What was in the specific answer for which I failed this audit? I can't see it afterwards!

Tags: support, review-audits, specific-answer

I was just reviewing posts in the Low Quality Post queue, and [failed this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7687728).

I had read the post and it looked to me like it made a decent attempt at providing a relevant answer to the question, and ended with a link to where more code could be found. I clicked "Looks OK", and was told I answered incorrectly.

I admittedly hadn't clicked over to the link, so I'm wondering if maybe it linked to something nefarious or spammy and I just didn't pick up on it because it was in the context of a post that looked reasonable, but when I tried to go back to view the post again it seems that the answer is missing.

Would someone with higher reputation have the ability to see the missing content so I can determine why I incorrectly answered the audit? This isn't a question about why something might be marked spam, as the linked possible duplicate -- this is a request for a [specific-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specific-answer) to be reposted so that I can understand whether my hunch as to what I missed is correct. I just want to determine whether it was a flawed audit or whether I wasn't paying as close attention as I ought to have been.

Comment: Not being able to find the post back is a pretty good hint why you failed the audit.  Hehe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Review audit: Answer marked as spam, unclear why](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289277/review-audit-answer-marked-as-spam-unclear-why)

Comment: That isn't a good duplicate for this question because I wasn't asking why a post was marked as spam, but rather asking for someone to post a specific audit answer that I was unable to see. A post about a different audit failure doesn't help me if I all I can do is guess at what was wrong with the post I failed -- I understand what spam is, I just wasn't able to determine for sure whether that was what I'd missed in this case.

Comment: What do you see when you go to the audit in the queue (via the link in your question)? See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed

Comment: There's just nothing there where you'd expect the answer to be, then the question is below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the answer:

> ```
> For Accessing data from edittext use the following code -
>
> EditText e = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);
>
> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getText().toString(), 0);
>
> You can get the whole code of edittext example here
>
> [EditText Example code Download][1]
>
>
>   [1]: http://dheeruapps.blogspot.in/
> ```

Did you notice the link, and especially where it points?

I think I remember that same user had lots more "answers" distributing this link, so it was a part of a pattern of blatant self-promotion / spam.

Comment: Ah, I noticed that the link pointed to a blog but not that it pointed to the root of the blog and not to a genuinely relevant post. I'll be more careful to double-check the links provided in answers -- It was just such a breath of fresh air to see something that wasn't just a link-only answer, I guess I let it go with too little scrutiny.

Comment: Thanks for reposting the answer so I could check my mistake!

Comment: @Deduplicator, so is this just an unfortunate audit choice then and the OP's action acceptable?

Comment: @ryanyuyu: No, it might not be that obvious, but it's not a bad audit. Spam isn't always blatant, thus checking the links for plausibility is neccessary.

Comment: @Deduplicator Ok just one more clarification: it's not just the pattern of spam from the user, but also the actual link was spam-ish and deserved a spam flag?

Comment: @ryanyuyu: In the queue, it only looks suspicious and worthy of further investigation. Which is the reason you get the links to the full question. And if you do that further investigation, it will become blatantly obvious that it's an audit, because nothing is there (and thus also that it belongs killed somehow). If it hadn't been an audit, you would get all the corroboration neccessary to SPAM-flag yourself. Or at least to ask a mod to take a closer look.

Comment: @Deduplicator ok thanks.  That is great advice to dig deeper and investigate the actual post before making judgements.