# Review queue audit question inconsistency

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

This is not a question about the review queue overall, but rather a question on a particular "Are you paying attention" question.  The question in question is this post on StackOverflow - [Can't run unit tests in Bluemix Build & Deploy Pipeline because the servers can't connect to ClearDB MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606154/cant-run-unit-tests-in-bluemix-build-deploy-pipeline-because-the-servers-can)

The answer that I rated was from user [Brian Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4691211/brian-martin) which has the response of the following:

> Today, the build and deploy servers are limited on outbound
>   connections to port 80 and 443. We are currently investigating if we
>   can loosen this restriction on these build servers and still maintain
>   the required security compliance. We recognize this is a big
>   limitation that needs to be addressed. Thanks for your bug report.
>
> Brian K. Martin IBM Bluemix Development

To me, this does not sound spammy, it is not link only and it addresses the issue at hand with the question, it is not possible.  After saying it looks OK, I failed the audit.

[image: Review Queue record in question]

My issue is not that I failed the audit, but rather, if you look at the question and accepted answer, it is a verbatim copy of the answer that was marked for deletion.  The accepted answer was also posted almost 3 hours later that our deleted answer.

[image: Current Question/Answer status]

Based on the evidence, is this a fair audit question?  There are other questions surrounding this issue, such as should this have been deleted to start with, however, I am not attempting to call a moderator's decision into question, but rather, this answer seems to be a poor candidate for a review queue audit.

Comment: @ryanyuyu How could it have been a copy of the accepted answer? it was three hours earlier! This is just a side effect of using an automated system to select audits. Sometimes a bad one will be chosen.

Comment: @KevinB - The accepted answer (4/13/2015 17:26) was a copy of the flagged answer (4/13/2015 14:44).  This added to my confusion on why I failed as the answer seemed ok (to me).  When I failed, I went to the question thinking perhaps it was an all together wrong answer.

Comment: @Tommy Yes, i was agreeing with you. The right option to choose in this case is still unclear even after following the link. (I guess other than the fact that it's deleted..)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Review audit: Answer marked as spam, unclear why](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289277/review-audit-answer-marked-as-spam-unclear-why)

Comment: @gnat - given that this is tagged disputed-review-audits, that implies that a specific instance of a review audit is in question. My review audit is not the same as the one that you have linked to. Are you sure these should be voted to be closed as it may discourage others from attempting to bring attention to a potential review audit issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marking that as spam was **wrong**; unfortunately it looks like the flag was approved by the mod converting to comment. Maybe the spam classification can be reversed; I'm not sure.

I'd say the conversion to comment was a fair move by Bill. The answer is not the ideal SO post; it seems to say "there's this problem with some server *at the moment*".

On the other hand, it's also apparently the only possible reply to the problem. (N.B. I have no knowledge of the tech involved.) Re-reading suggests that a change was made to some setting on the date of the answer, but that the change is semi-permanent. I'm not sure the question is close-worthy, because although it turns out to be just a bug report, no-one knows that when they have the problem. It also seems possible that another resolution will be found.*

The result of this square-peg-round-hole is a bad audit that falsely caught you. I think everyone did the best they could in this situation, including you; aside from getting the answer out of the audit list, I don't see anything more to be done.

---

*If the resolution turns out to be the service provider coming back and saying "fixed now!", it would probably make sense to close as "not reproducible" then, and direct the question towards removal as obsolete.

Comment: Made a bug-report for answer-to-comment not declining all but NAA and other flags... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290485/why-does-convert-to-comment-validate-spam-offensive-vlq-flags

Comment: "Get the answer out of the audit list" - that's what I was thinking might need to happen as it is not a clear cut decision either way, making for a questionable audit.  Posting here, I was looking for feedback on if that should be done or if I had misinterpreted the answer/question/review queue and this in fact is an OK audit question.

Comment: @Tommy: Yes, it's a catastrophically bad audit. Those happen. And it also highlights a bug in the mod-tool convert-to-comment. Now whether it should have been converted... I tend for no.

Comment: It should be done, @Tommy. The post was selected (automatically) as an audit solely because it was deleted as spam. It's not spam, thus it should not be an audit.

Comment: Another consideration is that it's unfair to Brian Martin, the poster of the answer, to have had it marked as spam. That is a black mark on his account, and I'm pretty sure he would have lost 100 rep as a result of the deletion.

Comment: The spam flag was wrong on this, I've gone ahead and cleared that flag from the answer.  That should clear up the problem with the audit.

Comment: Thanks, @bluefeet; that seems to resolve everything.