# Why does "convert to comment" validate SPAM / OFFENSIVE / VLQ - Flags?

Tags: bug, spam, offensive, convert-to-comment

The disputed review-audit [Review queue audit question inconsistency](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290478/review-queue-audit-question-inconsistency) demonstrates a bug in flag-validation:

While it is proper that deleting a post validates most flags, convert-to-comments, which is a mod-only action, should only ever validate NAA-flags.
The rest of the flags with the exception of other-flags which always need explicit handling **should be declined** instead.

**If a moderator judges it worth preserving as a comment, it better not be garbage, spam or offensive.** I'm reasonably certain our mods get that right.

Comment: Based on my knowledge, the process of deleting anything with a flag automatically validates the flag.  Converting to a comment, deletes the answer and thus marks the flag as helpful.  Ideally, the flag should be cleared before converting it to a comment.  I've now cleared that flag on that answer which should resolve the audit issue.

Comment: Well, the default for "delete" is not sane for "convert", and if the default is wrong it will often be used inadvertently anyway. Better for the proper thing to be the path of least resistance... and thanks for correcting that case.