# Why did I fail this review audit when the answer seemed legit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Today I failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7735566). Unfortunately I did not copy the answer and I cannot find it anymore, but it proposed CryptonorDB and contained a link to CryptonorDB with the disclaimer that said DB is relatively new and was created by the author of the answer. Now I am blocked from reviewing for two days because I ended up clicking on "Looks OK".

At first it seemed like any link-only answer, but then I visited the question page and compared it to the other answers. Like at most upvoted answers, the author said that it is relatively new but worth checking it out.

So I tried to leave the author a comment that he might want to include *why* to choose CryptonorDB or include a concise code example. The fact that I was not able to comment made me aware that this is either an audit or the author already deleted the answer. Nevertheless I thought if other *accepted and upvoted answers look very similar*, this one has a right to exist too.

**Was the answer deleted because the author advertises his own product?**
Please help me understand why I failed this audit so I can improve my reviewing.

Comment: *Was the answer deleted because the author advertises his own product*: yes, almost certainly, and this would not have been their only post with that link.

Comment: Note that the *question* should really be closed as off-topic too here. I've voted to close it now, that's a real spam magnet.

Comment: see also: [Review queue audit question inconsistency](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290478/839601)

Comment: Passing an audit like this is rather simple, the fact that you cannot find the post back is a dead giveaway that you are being audited.  But of course requires you to find out when you review, not after you failed the audit :)  Stop, Look, Listen, that's what audits are all about.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you for your explanation! By the way, good luck for the moderator election!