# Why did I fail on the audit review?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I failed the audit review https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24259562. My choice was "looks ok" but the answer has been "deleted as spam or offensive Sep 27 at 17:32".

Can you explain me why is this post spam or offensive?

EDIT:

I think it is not a duplicate of the [Review audit: Answer marked as spam, unclear why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289277). The question and answer [Review audit: Answer marked as spam, unclear why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289277) say that there is a link to a provate youtube channel with advertisement. The answer I reviewed contains link to a page with more details related to the topic in question. The answer itself contains useful information and the link leads to a good detail description. It is not a spam from my point of view.

EDIT 2: screenshot for users without sufficient permissions to see the discussed post.
[image: Screenshot of the post]

Comment: Is the post promoting a website? If yes, check if the user is spamming links to the website.

Comment: The post does not promote a product. Neither the link promotes a product. It least I have not find a promotion.

Comment: Maybe posts that have received upvotes (that one has gotten 3!) should not be put into the audit pool. IIRC the reverse is true (audits for known-good posts - a single downvote invalidates them), so flipping it around would make sense too for determining known-bad posts

Comment: @Blastfurnace: A link from SO to a site may indeed increase SEO of the target site. But it is valid for any site and I think it is not a goal to forbid all links. The link from the 'problematic' answer is https://www.ably.io/concepts/long-polling. The topic there is relevant to the question and there is not excessive advertisement at the site.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because it is also not clear why the link would be spam. My best bet is that the user posted the link in a lot of locations and was deleted for spam. But that is not visible from the single post itself.

Comment: Ok, The account was deleted due to improper behavior. But this particular post should not be used for audit because a reviewer should review a post and not overall user activity. And this post is valid.

Comment: A mod would need to clear the spam flags on that posts and maybe undelete and then re-delete. I would argue as well, that this audit is erroneous.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Hard to check if the user's been destroyed and normal people can't search for similar links in deleted posts. This looks like a case of the system using a post as an audit where it relies on knowledge gleanable from a prior state to determine that it's bad.

Comment: @CertainPerformance this particular spam ring was AstroTurfing their site and product in a series of posts and were ringvoting the content up. This account was spam-deleted (“Destroy”, says the option) for those reasons after I spam flagged the obvious cases. This one is more subtle, which means that the reviewer should *definitely* pay attention, because the post is also a copy-pasta, they were posting a load of these to seed an association between websockets and their brand.  The post score *increases* the need to keeping paying attention for such cases!

Comment: Can someone with sufficient reputation please edit this question with a screenshot? I would like to see this as an example of when to not approve.

Comment: The screenshot of the discussed post is added to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see the system message "*Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully*", the post was previously reported by other users as spam, or the system is tracking this as spam due to heuristics on the post stats.

In this case you **must** attempt to view the user's profile to see if there are other posts linking to the same website (spammy user), or whether the user is affiliated to the website in any way via the profile description or website link (undisclosed affiliation is also spam). Also, you should click-through to view the original post to [see if the review is an audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287852/584192) (to show that you have reviewed carefully and thoroughly).

If you had viewed the user profile or original post, you would have noted that either has been deleted, and therefore the review is an audit.

I have spoken to a CM and using posts by a spam-nuked user as LQP audits are intentionally set-up this way. If you think posts by spam-nuked users should not be used as audits, we can create a <kbd>[feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=feature-request+discussion+reviews+review-audits+low-quality-posts)</kbd>.

Comment: I am not sure if posts by a spam-nuked users should be LQP audits. I probably misunderstood what carefully means in this case and I reviewed the post only.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to view deleted content, but was there anything in that question that looked like spam? What was that link?

Comment: @giusti see comments on question above