# Bad review audit - non-spam answer deleted by Community as spam

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I just failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24668492) in the VLQ queue by clicking Looks OK when the post had been removed as spam.  I think this is actually a bad audit.

[The original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374347/3399890).

The post under review:
[image]

This is similar to [this disputed review audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390218/3399890) but it is on a different post.

In my case, the original posting account is on a temporary suspension for promotional content, and the answer itself does have a downvote, so presumably it was removed as part of suspending the user as per the comments on the other post.

That said, there isn't anything in this post itself (unless I am missing something) that makes this particular post spam or offensive.  It looks like an honest attempt to answer this question.  There are no links or other obvious promotion in the content.  There is not a "possible spam" warning on the review (and I don't remember seeing one when it first appeared).  There is some edit history on the post, but I can't view it (any more?).  It was also removed very recently after having been on the site for about 9 months.

Assuming I am correct about what happened here, I'm mostly concerned about others also hitting the same bad audit -- could it be removed from the pool of audits?

Comment: I agree. It *was* spammy, until Bhargav Rao♦ edited the spam link out (on Feb 23), after which it looks like a reasonable attempt to answer the question. Then it was deleted as spam 3 days ago. (There's only one downvote on it, and since it's deleted as spam, that vote must have come automatically from the spam flag that deleted it, rather than from a user actually voting.)