# Failed Review on post closed as "spam or offensive" even though it doesn't appear to be?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I'm asking to get **this *specific* question removed from future audits** - which is now has been - so it is not related to the questions suggested as duplicate.

I've just failed [this LQP review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27056234) because the answer "*was flagged as spam or offensive content*".

[image]

It's a code-only answer except for the YouTube link (which is also about Python so it looked ok) and as code-only answers are still valid answers, I thought it looked OK. The answer also directly referenced the `"h","e","l","l","o"` that was in the question itself.

What did I miss? After I failed the review, I looked a bit more into the user and they have no posts, so I guess the link was spam? Are we supposed to check into the users past posts on each review to decide if the user might be posting the same link or something?

My question is whether this a suitable post for audits, and can anything be done about it if it isn't. This is the second time recently that I've failed a review on a very similar style of "spam" answer - I suppose I should have known this time but I still don't see any obvious problem with the answers.

Comment: That specific user was blacklisted/reported by users to the Smoke Detector for posting the same link to that youtube video 3 times in a row. Two of those posts made it into SOCVR: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=VIKKY+OMKAR&user=&room=90230

Comment: @rene Thanks for the info. It sounds like its not an appropriate question for audit then - there is nothing obvious wrong with the question, just the users behaviour which we can't know in a review. Is there anything that can be done about removing questions like this from the audit so others don't fall foul of it too? As I said, that's the 2nd audit I failed with a question like that recently, and now I've a review ban. Also, I don't remember failing any other audits recently, so do you know if 2 failed "spam" audits are enough to trigger the ban?

Comment: First the post you're looking at is an answer, not a question. I agree it is not obvious from the answer nor from the context that remains that this is an obvious spam case. I'm not sure what options remain, except an mod fiddling with the answer to make it no longer show-up as audit. I doubt system imposed review bans can be lifted by a mod but we'll wait for one to come by and clarify that for us.

Comment: For those of us who are <10k, could a screenshot or quote be added to the question?  The answer is only displayed to review participants and (I think) users who can see deleted posts.

Comment: @rene Sorry yes, I meant answer! I got it (half) right in my question, but I've been reading so many failed-audit posts on meta I've "questions" on the brain :)

Comment: @RyanM I've edited the question with a screenshot.

Comment: These pop up now and again unfortunately. I've undeleted and redeleted the answer so that should bump it from being an audit in future and I've lifted the review suspension.

Comment: @FluffyKitten yeah, no harm done. I question my brain all the time.

Comment: Thanks for your help @JonClements! If I come across another question like this, should I post it here on meta (even if I don't fail it next time) so it can be fixed for other users?

Comment: @FluffyKitten no need for a meta post - if you happen to come across one again then you could mod flag with a custom reason explaining that it may be an unfair audit and possibly link to this post as well for additional context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Review audit: Answer marked as spam, unclear why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289277/review-audit-answer-marked-as-spam-unclear-why)